# HTML5 Image and Text are not inclined in the same place

Tags: html, xhtml, tags

I am learning HTML5 and I need some text along with the image . Image should be come on the left side and text should come on the center . what I am trying to do is I created a div layout into that I placed image and text but problem is that text is coming in the center but coming down to the image , not into the same side of the image..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header" style="height:110px;background-color:#383838;">
<img src="logo2.jpg" alt="AB" ></img>
<h1 style="text-align:center">A</h1>
<h2 style="text-align:center">B</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

jsFiddle of code http://jsfiddle.net/EVvG4/

Comment: Could you please try to explain yourself a bit better? What you want to achieve?

Comment: ya if i will run the above code..the output comes  Image then below to image text on center ...and I want the text should come with image not below to it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EVvG4/1/ Tell me if that's what you need.

Comment: I am not getting from this url but you can try this in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_class to check y text is coming below to image

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EVvG4/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try it yourself, I can't with that page...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="header" style="height:110px; width: 1024px; background-color:#383838; margin: 0 auto;">

<div id="img-container" style="position: absolute;">
    <img src="logo2.jpg" alt="AB" style=" width: 100px; margin: 0 auto;" />
</div>
<div id="both-container" style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
<div id="text-container" style="position: absolute;">
    <h1 style="text-align: center">A</h1>
    <h2 style="text-align:center">B</h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

For a header, if you want to float it in center:

```
.header
{
    (fixed width) width: 1024px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Then, if you want to float different stuff in it, you have several ways:

1. Using the **float: right/left** style
2. Using `div positions`: **position: absolute/relative...**

Positioning options: [Learn CSS positioning](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)